# Model Association Before and After Update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Say I have a Rails model and I want to get the state of a list of an association before and after an update to see the difference between them. How would I go about doing this? I had tried just doing a before_update and after_update callback to maintain an array of the association and taking a rejection of what was in the array after the update compared to before the update but it seems that my array is never matching the state before the update.

Any ideas?

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: lectures
#
#  id               :integer          not null, primary key
#  organization_id  :integer
#  training_type_id :integer
#  name             :string(255)
#  description      :text
#  start_date       :date
#  end_date         :date
#  training_method  :string(255)
#  trainer_name     :string(255)
#  trainer_phone    :string(255)
#  trainer_email    :string(255)
#  location         :string(255)
#  total_seats      :integer
#  available_seats  :integer
#  hours            :integer
#  created_at       :datetime
#  updated_at       :datetime
#

class Lecture < ActiveRecord::Base

  # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
  # Relations
  # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #

  belongs_to :organization

  belongs_to :training_type
  has_many :training_histories
  has_many :users, through: :training_histories

  # belongs_to :training_type

  # has_many :training_histories, inverse_of: :lecture, :autosave => true

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :training_histories

  # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
  # Validations
  # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #

  validates :name,
            :start_date,
            :end_date,
            :location,
            :organization,
            :trainer_email,
            :trainer_name,
            :hours,
            :presence => :true

  validate :start_must_be_before_end_date

  validates :trainer_email, email: true

  after_update :email_users_about_update, email_supervisors_about_signup

  def start_must_be_before_end_date
    errors.add(:start_date, "must be before end date") unless self.start_date <= self.end_date
  end

  def email_users_about_update
    self.training_histories.each do |history|
      UserMailer.updated_training_email(history.user, self).deliver unless history.completed
    end
  end

  def email_supervisors_about_signup
    binding.pry
    if self.users.changed?
      users_dif = self.users - self.users_was
      unless users_dif.nil?
       users_dif.each do |user|
       UserMailer.create_subordinate_training_sign_up(user.leader, user, self).deliver
       end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Have a look at `ActiveModel::Dirty` (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html). That module is included into `ActiveRecord::Base` models and works out of the box.

Comment: i dont think this will work since its a persisted attribute that im trying to map and the class implements activerecord

Comment: Sorry, I do not get the point. Dirty attributes work pretty well in ActiveRecord models. Can you add code to clarify your problem?

Comment: added the class im modifying in! basically i want email_supervisors_about_signup to fire everytime the users association gets updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an `after_add` callback:

```
# add the callback to our association
has_many :users, through: :training_histories, after_add: :invite_to_training

# this method gets called when a user is added
private
def invite_to_training(user)
  UserMailer.create_subordinate_training_sign_up(user.leader, user, self).deliver
end
```

For more information on association callbacks see: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods-label-Association+callbacks

Comment: i get a wrong number of arguments error though after saving or updating now?

Comment: never mind! i forgot to remove something that caused a problem. thanks for the help!